# Updating Status Dialog from Thread in MFC

Tags: multithreading, mfc

I have a function performing a large amount of work and I want to be able to provide a status dialog in MFC (although I think this question is pertinent to any GUI).

Normally I would just create a thread and then post messages to the main window for updates.  However, in this case the function also needs to work from non-MFC applications, such at MATLAB and Python.  Therefore, I seem to have two choices, neither one I like.

The first option is to include the MFC code in the thread surrounded by #ifdefs.  If figure I will need about five of these, although I could probably combine some of them.

The second option is to define a variable in the main window that the thread updates.  The main window would have to create a timer to check that variable and update the GUI.  This would entirely remove the MFC code from the thread, but is still a kludge.

My question is, which do you think is the lesser of the two evils, surrounding the thread code by #ifdefs, or implementing a timer?  Better still, is there a third option that I haven't thought of?

Thank you.

Comment: Pass a window handle to the thread proc (or `nullptr` if not available) and post update messages only, if the handle is valid.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really solve the problem.  I would still have to used #ifdefs for non-WIndows programs for things such as the Windows header file, the CWnd pointer and the PostMessage function.

Comment: Well, not really. You could define an interface for the notifications, and implement platform-specific versions. Platforms without a GUI would simply instantiate the do-nothing implementation. Dependency injection is a common mechanism for this.